# Can I make visual studio 2012 use a nickname for a file?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-2012

I'm currently developing a dynamics CRM 2011 customization using the 5.0.18 SDK project type. This project type splits webresources into folders for each type of web resource. So I have a folder `WebResources`, with in there a folder labeled `Cascading Stylesheet (CSS)` with in there a stylesheet with filename `membership.css` and Unique Name `acm_membership_css`. I also have in the `WebResources` folder a folder `Web Page (HTML)` with in there a html file with filename `acm_membership_generator_html.htm` and Unique Name `acm_membership_generator_html`.

The problem I have is that when I'm developing this in Visual Studio and need to see the effect of my stylesheet on my page, I need to write this reference (refering to the filename):

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../Cascading Stylesheet (CSS)/membership.css"/>
```

However, this reference does not work in CRM. In CRM, all webresources are located in the same folder and require me to refer to them using only the unique name. In this case, I need to use:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="acm_membership_css" />
```

Because of this difference in reference method, I need to use both methods to refer to them, which I think is a bit sloppy. I want to tell VS 2012: This link to `acm_membership_css` actually refers to `../Cascading Stylesheet (CSS)/membership.css`, treat it as such when rendering the CSS in the WYSIWYG editor.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking the Resharper suggestions, I noticed that Resharper allows you to set a Path mapping that substitutes paths for resources that are deployed to a different location.